# MYSQL - generating subset sequence in a table

Tags: mysql, sequence, subset

I have the following table

```
Id   Value
1     3
1     12
1     67
2     7
2     99
5     30
5     33
5     4
5     87
5     12
5     1
```

I'd like to update it to have this table.

```
Id  UniqueIdBySubSet    Value
1           1             3
1           2             12
1           3             67
2           1             7
2           2             99
5           1             30
5           2             33
5           3             4
5           4             87
5           5             12
5           6             1
```

I found the perfect thread on SO, but it was for mssql. I use mysql 4.1.10.

The other thread can be found here: [Generating sequences for subsets of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492375/generating-sequences-for-subsets-of-a-table).

Does anyone knows how I can do that in mysql ?

Thank you,
Jean-Francois

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET  @r := 0;
SET  @id := 0;
UPDATE  mytable m
SET     m.UniqueIdBySubSet = IF(@id = id, @r := @r + 1, @r := (@id := id) - id)
ORDER BY
        id, value;
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried and test your answer, and it doesn't work. Here's the value I get for the example up there.
1, 1, 3
1, 2, 12
1, 3, 67
2, 1, 7
2, 2, 99
5, 3, 1
5, 4, 4
5, 5, 12
5, 6, 30
5, 7, 33
5, 8, 87

I've been working with it for about 20 minutes, but I don't seem to get it to work. The idea seems great though, I think it could work.

If you have any idea, feel free to add more informations.

Comment: I've been able to make it work. But the first index is not 1 anymore, but 0.

SET  @r := -1;
SET  @id := -1;
UPDATE  mytable m
SET     m.UniqueIdBySubSet = CASE
WHEN @id = 0 THEN @r := (@id := m.Id) - m.Id                       
WHEN m.Id = @id THEN @r := @r + 1
ELSE @r := (@id := m.Id) - m.Id
END
ORDER BY m.Id, m.Value;

Thanks for the input. It was really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write a quick script to do it. It should take less than 10 lines of code in php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find [this article](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/05/mysql-update-multiple-rows-with-one-single-query.html) useful. In short: you can't do it in exactly one query, but you can do it in two (load your data into a new table and execute an insert statement).